# Testing jquery thats depend on version with Js-test.driver

Tags: javascript, jquery, unit-testing, js-test-driver

im new to js-test-driver and have some questions

how can i test this jquery event?

ex verify that the event runs Search() if letter > 9

```
$("#search").live('keydown', function () {
//start search after 10 letters
if ($(this).val().length > 9) {
    Search();
}});
```

Does anybody has some documentation for js-test-driver?

How does Js-test.driver handle functionality thats depends on versions of my jquery, if run Version 1.6?

thanks /K

Comment: solved this by myself

To trigger jquery event:
jQuery("#testButton").trigger('keydown');

To test jquery:
Inluce library in conf.

Answer (score 0):

> Solved this by myself. To trigger jQuery:

```
event: jQuery("#testButton").trigger('keydown');
```

> To test jQuery, include the library in conf.